# componentDidMount() is not getting called but only in a particular circumstance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Just a heads up: this is a really strange problem. I'll do my best to clearly explain the issue. This is happening in my `ReactJs` app using `React Router`.

I have some components that require some type of parameter coming from the URL. I also have components that do NOT depend on a parameter.

If I go to components that do **not** require any parameters, there are no problems whatsoever.

So, I go to my `Home`, then `Account List`, neither of which require any parameters, I can go back and forth as many times as I like, there's no problem.

However, if I go to a component that uses a parameter, then try to go another component that uses a parameter, I then get an error. The error indicates that the component `react-router` is supposed to load is NOT mounted properly which throws an error telling me that the data the child component needs is missing. The errors I'm getting are pretty simple ones. They simply say something like:

> this.props.something is required but undefined

Here's my routes in `App.jsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

// Import components here
// Just showing one for brevity
import Home from '../components/home/Home';

import * as appActions from '../actions/app-actions';

class App extends Component {

   constructor(props) {

      super(props);
   }

   render() {

      return(

          <div>
              <Switch>
                 <Route exact path="/member" component={Home} />
                 <Route exact path="/member/accounts" component={Accounts} />
                 <Route exact path="/member/projects" component={ProjectsList} />
                 <Route path="/member/projects/profile/:id" component={ProjectProfile} />|
                 <Route exact path="/member/tasks" component={TasksList} />
                 <Route path="/member/tasks/profile/:id" component={TaskProfile} />
              </Switch>
          </div>
      );

   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {

    return {
        member: state.member.memberData
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {

    return {

        actions: bindActionCreators(appActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

As you can see from the routes, both `ProjectProfile` and `TaskProfile` components require ID's. Furthermore, both `ProjectProfile` and `TaskProfile` components are rather simple parent components that do two things:

1. Make an API call to load data in the `componentDidMount()` event
2. They also load the correct child component based on user's screen resolution

Here's my `ProjectProfile` component and the `TaskProfile` is pretty much identical to this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

// Actions
import * as projectProfileActions from '../../../actions/project-profile-actions';

// Components
import Desktop from './ProjectProfileDesktop';
import Mobile from './ProjectProfileMobile';

class ProjectProfile extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
    };

    componentDidMount() {

        const id = this.props.match.params.id;
        this.props.actions.getData(id);
    }

    render() { 

        return (
                <div className="height-100 width-100">
                    <div className="height-100 width-100 row row-clean">
                    {this.props.ui.isDesktop || this.props.ui.isTablet ? <Desktop />
                        : this.props.ui.isMobile ? <Mobile />
                        : null}
                    </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        ui: state.app.window
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {

    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(projectProfileActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProjectProfile);
```

The strangest part about this is that if I keep going back and forth between `ProjectProfile` and any other component and stay away from `TaskProfile`, there are no problems. I can even hit `ProjectProfile` with different ID's and everything works fine. It all fails only when I go to **another** component with parameter. I can do the same with `TaskProfile`. I can keep hitting `TaskProfile` with different ID's OR go back and forth between `TaskProfile` and any component **without** a parameter and everything works fine.

Only if I go to `ProjectProfile` first, then try to go to `TaskProfile` or vice versa, the error occurs.

The error is simply telling me that the data `ProjectProfileDesktop` requires is not there.

Further inspection shows me that after loading a component with a parameter, if I go to another component with a parameter, I'm just NOT hitting the `componentDidMount()` method in the second component. Looks like something in the `render()` method is causing an issue and preventing it from going to `componentDidMount()`. I'm not sure what the issue is because I'm not getting any errors. I put a `debugger` at the top of the `render()` method. Though I'm not seeing an exact error, the flow shows me that something is definitely going wrong.

Please also notice that I'm using `withRouter`. I've seen some issues involving `withRouter` but again, I couldn't find anything concrete so far.

I also want to mention that I also have Stripe provider wrapping my `App` component. Not sure if this is playing a role in this problem as well. Here's what the `render()` looks like in my `index.js`:

```
render(
   <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter history={browserHistory}>
          <StripeProvider apiKey="my_key">
              <App />
          </StripeProvider>
       </BrowserRouter>
   </Provider>,
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I'd appreciate some pointers on this.

**UPDATE:**

A behavior I'm observing is that after loading a component with a param, when I hit the second component with a param, I hit the `render()` method first and right after the first `createElement`, the code jumps to `ReactInstrumentation.debugTool.onBeginLifeCycleTimer` -- see screen shot below.

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

At this point, I'm convinced the issue is not caused by `react-router` because I hard-coded the ID I needed into the component so that I don't depend on `react-router` or anything else to get it.

I also removed `/:id` parameter from the routes for my `TaskProfile` and `ProjectProfile` components.

I still get the same behavior. So, something is preventing `componentDidMount()` method from being called. I also tried `componentDidUpdate()` to see if it was being called and it is NOT. I placed `componentWillUnmount()` in both components and as I navigate elsewhere in the app, in both components `componentWillUnmount()` gets called so one could argue that both components are unmounting OK.

So the bottom line is that something in the `render()` method is preventing `componentDidMount()` or any other lifecycle method from being called but this is only happening in this particular circumstance.

I'd appreciate any suggestions at this point!!!

Comment: did you check if the component is unmounting? I think it's something with the routes and it never unmounts.

Comment: @andrewgi I'm hitting the `debugger` I placed in `componentWillUnmount()` in both the parent and the child components so looks like it unmounts OK.

Comment: Can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on https://codesandbox.io/s/new?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's been more than a week I've been banging my head against the wall on this issue and it's finally solved. Admittedly, lots of concepts that I thought I understood became even clearer in the process.

The error was due a logical error on my part that handled "isLoading" animation logic -- yes, as simple and stupid as that!!!

What I really wanted to share here are the lessons I've learned  for everyone who may experience a similar behavior in the future.

1. You should hit `componentDidMount()` every time you load your component. Even if you go back and forth to load the same component. But you hit `componentDidMount()` ONLY IF your component was unmounted in the first place. If the component does not get unmounted, you will NOT hit `componentDidMount()` in your subsequent uses of the component. So look at your logic carefully to see if your component gets unmounted if you navigate away from it. I think the easiest way to see if this is happening is by adding `componentWillUnmount()` method with a `debugger` in it. If you're hitting this method when you navigate away from your component, that means it is unmounting.
2. Did lots of research during this process to see where the best place to make API calls to fetch data and it's definitely clear that `componentDidMount()` is still the best place to do it. Having said that you may need additional logic in your `componentDidMount()` to make sure you don't make any unnecessary API calls because your data may still be in your store.
3. During my research, some suggested that it's better to use `componentWillReceiveProps()` method to make my API call to fetch data. This is bad advice! As a matter of fact, `componentWillReceiveProps()`, `componentWillUpdate()` and `componentWillMount()` methods are being deprecated so we should not use them for two reasons: future compatibility and following best practices. Here's more info on why they're being deprecated: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html
4. Maybe the most important lesson is this: the cause of the problem may be much simpler than you think -- it usually is -- and the logic in your code may be the cause of the issue -- it usually is!

Hope these lessons will help others find their solutions quickly and painlessly!

Comment: How does it happen that the same instance gets unmounted and then mounted again? I don't same any code that saves the component object anywhere.

Answer (score -4):

ComponentDidMount it's called just one time, when the component is mounted. As you are using a prop to then make an api call, I would use componentWillReceiveProps and check props and then make an api call.

If you want yo check that the componentDidMount is used by your flow, use a console.log to check it.

Regards!

Comment: Shouldn't `componentDidMount()` be called everytime the component loads? So if I go from component A to B, then back to A, shouldn't I hit `componentDidMount()` in component A?

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. He already said that is never reaches the `componentDidMount()`

Comment: He said that he reaches the `componentDidMount()` on the first time, just don't on the next ones

Comment: And Lucas is right. React will just call `componentDidMount()` when needed. And sometimes will just call `componentDidUpdate()` when it updates. However, you should not use `componentWillReceiveProps` anymore. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: @MuriloCruz Keep in mind, these are two separate components. I'm NOT hitting `componentDidMount()` even the first time IF I'm coming from a component that uses a parameter. I do hit it on the first component with parameter but not the second component with parameter.

Comment: Yes, and that happens because React is re-using the component that was rendered on the first time, so it is calling `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: it is calling `componentDidUpdate` with the "second component"'s properties, instead of unmounting and mounting again

Comment: @MuriloCruz I placed the `componentDidUpdate()` method in both components and it's NOT getting called. So, the issue here is not as simple as that. Strangely, `componentWillUnmount()` gets called in both components as I navigaete elsewhere in the app. So arguably, both components are unmounting. At this point, I'm also convinced that this issue is not caused by `react-router` because I hard-coded the ID I need into the component and removed `/:id` from the route. I still get the same behavior.