# componentDidMount() on reloading component

Tags: reactjs

I have components A and B, both of which have their own `componentDidMount()` methods. Think of them as two separate modules that are NOT loaded together. It's either A or B but not together.

My simple question is this:

If I hit component A, then B, then back to A, will `componentDidMount()` in component A be called on the second one?

When I read the documentation, it states that `componentDidMount()` is called only once and `componentDidUpdate()` is called in all component updates but I'm not 100% clear if this is happening in the entire life cycle of my app.

I'm trying to figure out the logic for API calls. I may or may not need to make an API call for component A again so I have some logic that handles that. Just trying to make my logic work for making that call.

So, the question simply is, will I hit `componentDidMount()` in component A on subsequent loads during a user's session? A user session may last a long time during which the user may come back to both component A and B many a times.

Comment: How are you navigating between each component? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm using `react-router`. This is a related question to another one where you can see my code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827695/not-hitting-componentdidmount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, every time you switch components you call again for `componentDidMount()`.
More about that here - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

The logic for API calls in React itself is most like:

- Create container which call for API in componentDidMount method.
- Create external dumb components which are imported to the container, call them in the `render()` method and pass the data via `props`
- Create logic which is executing which component should you call now( `react-router-dom` library is also good approach for conditional rendering)

I hope I explained you that a bit. feel free to ask some questions!

Comment: That's what I thought. I pretty much have the structure you've mentioned and having trouble with two components with params but haven't been able to figure out what's causing the issue. Here's my post on that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827695/not-hitting-componentdidmount

Comment: A comment on my other post is suggesting that I may not always hit `componentDidMount()` on subsequent loads.

Comment: You always hit `componentDidMount()` when you render component first time. When component is rendered and you just update It then `componentDidUpdate` is called. You can try to check if `componentDidUpdate` is called instead of `componentDidMount()`

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Now, it's clear. Whether or not we hit `componentDidMount()` depends on whether or not the component was mounted or unmounted. If the component is still mounted when we go back to it, we don't hit `componentDidMount()`. If by loading another component, the original component gets unmounted, we will hit `componentDidMount()` again, when we load it again.