# componentDidMount() is not getting triggered in certain circumstances

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have two components which have an id parameter for routing. Everything works fine if I navigate to component A, followed by component A again. But if i navigate to component A and then component B, my app crashes because componentDidMount() of component B is not triggered here. Same case with component A.

Please help.

[This is the exact problem I'm facing, but unsure as to how to fix this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827695/componentdidmount-is-not-getting-called-but-only-in-a-particular-circumstance)

Comment: This question exactly explains my issue, but I'm not able to understand how to get this fixed from the solution given there @Tristan

Comment: As pointed out in that post you linked, it could be a logical problem and/or the component isn't unmounted, so DidMount won't be called. I'd suggest trying all the things pointed out in that answer and after that try to be more specific when asking a question, this is really too vague.

Comment: Thank you all, the issue was because of my loading animation logic. it works now!